# chrome won't open video in external app

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have a website that serves raw .mp4 files; Google Chrome stopped asking which app to open the videos in when I click on a link to one of the videos. I've tried clearing the defaults for which app to open for links and I've verified that my video player declares an intent for `*`. How to I change Google Chrome back to allowing me to open a link directly to a video in another app?

Comment: Which device(s)/OS versions/version of Chrome are you testing on?

Comment: android 7.0, blu vivo 8, chrome 69.0.3497.76

Comment: What changed between it working and not working?

Comment: @DanHulme From what I can tell, the only thing that changed is chrome updating